# What's the difference between many functions that use to write things to an element?

Tags: javascript, dom

There are many functions that can be used to write things to an element. They are

```
document.createTextNode()
innerHTML
insertAdjacentHTML()
textContent or innerText
nodeValue
createTextNode
```

I wonder what's the difference between these methods and properties? Thanks in advance!

I have searched for many posts but couldn't find any good answers.

Comment: I recommend to look them up on MDN. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode. Note that innerHTML, textContent, innerText and nodeValue are not functions. Also note that they have nothing in particular to do with JavaScript, they are part of the DOM API.

Comment: The best and most rewarding solution would be for you research each one individually and judge the difference for yourself. You would learn the most that way.

Comment: `innerHTML`, `textContent`, `innerText` and `nodeValue` aren't functions, they're properties of existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Some are newer than others, some originated as proprietary and some were driven by standards. The newer methods like insertAdjacentHTML are generally faster on my browser according to this benchmark (http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-insertadjacenthtml-vs-dom/9). The MDN is a good place to use as a reference if you're interested in compatibility.

I personally use insertAdjacentHTML the most because I find the api the most flexible and its the fastest I've seen over several benchmarks.